# File path in created external table changes daily after database refresh

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have created an external table in Azure Synapse Analytics in AzureDataLakeStorageGen2.
Then I am using this the data from the external table in another SQL query.

When I run the command the table is being created, and the SELECT statement is working fine.
The other SQL query is also working fine.

The problem is that after an overnight refresh of the database the file path I have used to create the external table changes, and the related report/sql query is returning an error, which is normal (the file path is provided in BULK parameter of OPENROWSET function).

Please see below the code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reports.FileIamCreating
WITH
(
    LOCATION ='/reports/CreatedFleName/',
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureDataLakeStorageGen2,
    FILE_FORMAT = csv
)
AS 
SELECT
    Reference,
    CAST('250.00' AS FLOAT) AS [Invoiced costs]
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://XName.dfs.core.windows.net/abc/tables/SomeFileName/F090863C-41D9-4022-A5D1-B40353F1478A_156134_0-1.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        HEADER_ROW = TRUE,
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS tbl1
WHERE Reference IN (
    '100725',
'107575',
'107707',
'108771')
```

The bit that I have noticed is changing daily is the string (the file name I think) after SomeFileName/.....
The info provided in the BULK argument of OPENROWSET function.
.... BULK 'https://XName.dfs.core.windows.net/abc/tables/SomeFileName/F096663C-41K9-4022-A5D1-B40353ZZZZZ_156884_0-1.csv'

I was hoping someone can advise me of a way I can fix this without the use of a Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Change the BULK storage path to `https://XName.dfs.core.windows.net/abc/tables/SomeFileName/`. The `select` query will then return data from all the files in that folder so I guess you will need a way to filter the results.